# XSLT - multiple format output with 1 xlst file

Tags: xml, xslt

is it possible to have 2 output method in 1 xsl file?
I wanted to achieve this
html folder <- all html files in it
root(main folder) <- xml files 
 
My below codes produces only xml files , no html-folder folder created nor html files

Below is the xlst:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

<xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('chapter1', '.html')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$filename"/>
<xsl:result-document href="main-folder/html-folder/{$filename}" format="html">


<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>
<xsl:result-document href="mainfolder/index.xml" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
```

Comment: You've shown us snippets of code out of context - xsl:result-document can't appear as a sibling of xsl:output. There's clearly a bug in your code, which you have carefully removed so that we can't help you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but review first your XSL to ensure you follow these rules:

- Always close properly each node.
- Output method should be defined just once per stylesheet/result-document.
- When using result-document, the same file should not be overwritten.

The output method (as well as `format` and `indent`) in a result-document must be set through the proper attributes:

```
<xsl:result-document method="xml" format="" indent="yes" ...>
```

Fixing your XSL would be like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('chapter1', '.html')"/>

<xsl:result-document href="main-folder/html-folder/{$filename}" method="html" indent="yes">
    ...
</xsl:result-document>

<xsl:result-document href="mainfolder/index.xml" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
    ...
</xsl:result-document>
```

Official documentation of [result-document](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

It still doesnt work. Could it be there conflict somewhere?
Originally they are 2 seperate xslt file, when run seperately, the output came out fine. When combine the codes into 1 xslt file, seems like the codes at bottom generate xml file appear, but the top codes for creating the sub-folder and html files does not work.

Comment: OK. In that case, could you post the combining XSL? (Or, at least, the minimum part to verify the problem).